# Combinatorial game

Tags: algorithm, combinatorics

Here's the game:

> There is a string of 0s and 1s and in each turn a player is allowed to
>   convert a set of contiguous 1s to 0s. A player can convert at most k
>   contiguous 1s to 0s and has to convert at least one 1 to 0 in his
>   move. The player who is unable to make a move loses.

Example:

10100111 (k=2)

Here the winning move would be: 10100101 (converted the 2nd last 1 to 0)

It's a 2 player impartial game and I tried to analyse it as a variant of nim game. There are n heaps each heap with a<sub>i</sub> marbles (**n** sets of contiguous 1s). A player can split a heap into 2 heaps by removing at most k marbles from anywhere in that heap. Supposing a heap has 5 marbles (`*****`) and you split the heap by removing k=2 marbles from position 2 (`* **`). Also, if you would remove the first or last k marbles, the heap wouldn't split, only its size would be reduced by k.

Can this model help find the strategy for the original game? If yes, what would be the optimal strategy?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Can't you simply map a winning strategy for the equivalent nim game (a-la sprague-grundy) to your game.

Comment: Actually I'm not very good finding winning strategy for nim-like games. That's what I need help with.

Comment: This is a variation of **[Nim](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nim)**. The game is solved and a perfect strategy - for any position - is easy to find.

Comment: @ypercube Have you come across this kind of game before? If yes, can you give me a link to the resource?

Comment: I already added a link to the wikipedia page about Nim. The strategy is the same as Nim. Find a move that leads to a "P-position" (previous player wins) and play it. Whatever the opponent plays (he has the same options as Nim, plus a few more from the splitting option), the result will be an "N-position" (next player wins), and you'll then be able to do the same (find a move that leads to a P-position.)

Answer (score 0):

As ypercube mentioned, game can be solved and for each position it is possible to show is it winning (N-position) or losing (P) position.

It is enough to consider:

- Initial losing (P) position is string with `n` zeros,
- Winning (N) position is any position from where is a move to some P-position,
- P-position is a position which every move lead to N-position.

With that it is easy to find value of each position by starting with initial position, find next N-positions, from these N-positions find (possible) P-positions, ...

Here is a python code that solves this game:

```
from itertools import product
from collections import defaultdict

class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, n, k):
        self.n, self.k = n, k

    def states(self):              # All strings with 0|1 of length n
        return (''.join(x) for x in product(('0', '1'), repeat=self.n))

    def set_zeros(self, c, i, l):  # Set zeros in c from position i with length l
        return c[:i] + '0'*l + c[i+l:]

    def next_positions(self, c):   # All moves from given position
        for i in xrange(self.n):
            if c[i] == '1':        # First '1'
                yield self.set_zeros(c, i, 1)
                for j in xrange(1, self.k):
                    if i+j < self.n and c[i+j] == '1':
                        yield self.set_zeros(c, i, j+1)
                    else:
                        break

    def lost_positions(self):  # Initial lost position(s)
        return ['0'*self.n]

    def solve(self):
        next_pos = {}               # Maps position to posible positions after a move
        prev_pos = defaultdict(set) # Maps position to posible positions before that move
        win_lose = {}               # True - win/N-position, False - lose/P-position, None - not decided
        for s in self.states():
            win_lose[s] = None
            next_pos[s] = set(self.next_positions(s))
            for n in next_pos[s]:
                prev_pos[n].add(s)
        # Initial loses positions
        loses_to_check = set(self.lost_positions())
        for c in loses_to_check:
            win_lose[c] = False
        #
        while loses_to_check:
            lost_c = loses_to_check.pop()
            for w_pos in prev_pos[lost_c]:    # Winning moves
                if win_lose[w_pos] is None:
                    win_lose[w_pos] = True
                    for x in prev_pos[w_pos]: # Check positions before w_pos for P-position
                        if all(win_lose[i] for i in next_pos[x]):
                            win_lose[x] = False
                            loses_to_check.add(x)
        return win_lose

comb = '10100111'
g = Game(len(comb), 2)
win_lose = g.solve()
print comb, win_lose[comb]
```

Note: changing/overriding methods `states()`, `next_positions(c)`, `lost_positions()` is enough to implement solver for similar games.